# State machine translates text into executable python code [v2]

Tags: c, strings, coordinate-system, state-machine, compiler

A few days ago I started writing my own compiler-like program which has the goal to compile plain text into executable python code. After I let my first version review [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222510/heavily-limited-premature-compiler-translates-text-into-excecutable-python-code), I made huge changes to the overall code and added the possibility of adding rectangles. I try to add all the suggested improvements as best as I could, please do not feel offended, if I missed one of your suggestions.

My final goal is to write a program which compiles text into executable python code, which then will display a 3D-Diagram containing all geometric shapes when executed.

At the moment, the user has to provide a text similar to this:

```
(1.2,45,6)
(7,8,5)
(10,77,88)
(99999,1,1)
R((1,1,1),(2,2,2),(1,3,4))
(5,7,6)
(1,2,3)
(4,5,6)
R((2,3,4),(9,9,9),(3,4,5))
  P(2,1,1)
```

where R(...) symbolizes rectangles and P(...) is an acronym for a profane point. I added the formatting mistake of the last line, purposely, to show that the compiler does not care about spaces.
This plain text will be compiled to a python-code similar (depending on the exact preferences of the code) like this.

```
points =  [
(1.2,45,6),
(7,8,5),
(10,77,88),
(99999,1,1),
]
points.extend([
(5,7,6),
(1,2,3),
(4,5,6),
(2,1,1),
])
rectangels =  [
((1,1,1),(2,2,2),(1,3,4)),
((2,3,4),(9,9,9),(3,4,5)),
]
print(points)
print(rectangels)
```

For the sake of me, you and all humankind I quickly realized that rewriting the code into a state machine is the proper way to go after suggested by [@Edward](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39848/edward).

So how could I further improve the following code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SPACE_FOR_POINTS 4
#define SPACE_FOR_RECTANGLES 4
/*For some reason, maximum size of any double represetend as a string:
 StackOverflow: What is the maximum length in chars needed to represent any double value?
 */
#define MAX_DIGITS_DOUBLE 3 + DBL_MANT_DIG - DBL_MIN_EXP
#define MAX_DIGITS_POINTS 5 + 3*MAX_DIGITS_DOUBLE
#define MAX_DIGITS_RECT 17+9*MAX_DIGITS_DOUBLE

void printPointList(char appened, char** points, int index);
void printRectangleList(char appened, char** rectangles, int index);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fp == NULL)return errno;

    //Do parsing

    char** points; //all future points will be stored here
    points = malloc(SPACE_FOR_POINTS * sizeof(char*)); //for the moment, make space for SPACE_FOR_POINTS
    if(points != NULL){
        for(int i = 0; i < SPACE_FOR_POINTS; i++){
            /*
             This is a point to be stored:
             (double,double,double)\0
             Calloc is better, because we can later break
             creating the list of points/rectangels, when first char is not '(',
             which is not necessarily the case for malloc.
             */
            points[i] = calloc(MAX_DIGITS_POINTS,1);

            if(points[i] == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate enough memory to perform compilation.");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate enough memory to perform compilation.");
        return -1;
    }

    char** rectangles; //all future regtangles will be stored here
    rectangles = malloc(SPACE_FOR_RECTANGLES*sizeof(char*)); /*for the moment, make space for
                                                             SPACE_FOR_RECTANGLES */
    if(points != NULL){
        for(int i = 0; i < SPACE_FOR_RECTANGLES; i++){
            /*
             This is a rectangle to be stored:
             ((double,double,double),(double,double,double),(double,double,double))\0

             Calloc is better, because we can later break
             creating the list of points/rectangels, when first char is not '(',
             which is not necessarily the case for malloc.
             */
            rectangles[i] = calloc(MAX_DIGITS_RECT, 1);
            if(rectangles[i] == NULL){
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate enough memory to perform compilation.");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate enough memory to perform compilation.");
        return -1;
    }

    char bool_appended_rectangle = 0; //Was a list already printed?
    char bool_appended_points = 0; //Was a list already printed?
    int numbers_written = 0; //counter
    int points_index = -1;
    int rectangels_index = -1;
    size_t actual_index = 0; //counter

    enum{name, openparen, comma, number, endparen, error} state = endparen;
    enum{point, rectangle} shape = point;

    //State machine
    for (char ch = fgetc(fp); ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(fp)) {
        if(isspace(ch)){
            continue;
        }
        switch(state){
        case name:
            if(ch == '('){
                state = openparen;
                switch (shape) {
                    case rectangle:
                        rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                        break;
                    case point:
                        points[points_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                state = error;
            }
            break;
        case openparen:
            if(ch == '('){
                switch (shape) {
                    case rectangle:
                        rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                        state = openparen;
                        break;
                    case point:
                        state = error;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(isdigit(ch)){
                numbers_written++;
                switch (shape) {
                    case rectangle:
                        rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                        state = number;
                        break;
                    case point:
                        points[points_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                        state = number;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            break;
        case number:
                if(isdigit(ch)){
                    switch (shape) {
                        case rectangle:
                            rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                            break;
                        case point:
                            points[points_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if(ch == ','){
                    switch (shape) {
                        case rectangle:
                            if(numbers_written <= 9){
                                rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                                state = comma;
                            } else {
                                state = error;
                            }
                            break;
                        case point:
                            if(numbers_written <= 3){
                                points[points_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                                state = comma;
                            } else {
                                state = error;
                            }
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if(ch == ')'){
                        switch (shape) {
                        case rectangle:
                            if(numbers_written%3 == 0){
                                rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                                state = endparen;
                            } else {
                                state = error;
                            }
                            break;
                        case point:
                            //printf("%d", numbers_written);
                            if(numbers_written == 3){
                                state = endparen;
                                points[points_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                            } else {
                                state = error;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if(ch == '.'){
                    points[points_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                    break;
                }
                state = error;
                break;
        case endparen:
                switch (state) {
                    case point:
                        points[points_index][actual_index++] = '\0';
                        break;
                    case rectangle:
                        rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = '\0';
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                if(ch == '(' || ch == 'P'){
                    if(++points_index >= SPACE_FOR_POINTS){
                        printPointList(bool_appended_points, points, points_index-1);
                        bool_appended_points = 1;
                        //clear all Strings
                        for(int i = 0; i < points_index; i++){
                            points[i] = calloc(MAX_DIGITS_POINTS, 1);
                        }
                        points_index = 0;
                    }
                }
                if(ch == '('){
                    actual_index = 0;
                    points[points_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                    shape = point;
                    state = openparen;
                    numbers_written = 0;
                    break;
                }
                if(ch == 'P'){
                    actual_index = 0;
                    state = name;
                    shape = point;
                    numbers_written = 0;
                    break;
                }
                if(ch == 'R'){
                    if(++rectangels_index >= SPACE_FOR_RECTANGLES){
                        printRectangleList(bool_appended_rectangle, rectangles, rectangels_index-1);
                        bool_appended_rectangle = 1;
                        //clear all strings
                        for(int i = 0; i < rectangels_index; i++){
                            rectangles[i] = calloc(MAX_DIGITS_RECT, 1);
                        }
                        rectangels_index = 0;
                    }
                    actual_index = 0;
                    state = name;
                    shape = rectangle;
                    numbers_written = 0;
                    break;
                }
                if(ch == ','){
                    if(shape == rectangle){
                        if(numbers_written < 9){
                            rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                            state = comma;
                        } else {
                            state = error;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if(ch == ')'){
                    if(shape == rectangle){
                        rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                        rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = '\0';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                state = error;
                break;
        case comma:
                switch (shape) {
                    case point:
                        if(isdigit(ch)){
                            numbers_written++;
                            state = number;
                            points[points_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                            break;
                        }
                        state = error;
                        break;
                    case rectangle:
                        if(isdigit(ch)){
                            numbers_written++;
                            rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                            state = number;
                            break;
                        }
                        if(ch == '('){
                            rectangles[rectangels_index][actual_index++] = ch;
                            state = openparen;
                            break;
                        }
                        state = error;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Corrupted File.");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    printPointList(bool_appended_points, points, points_index);
    printRectangleList(bool_appended_rectangle, rectangles, rectangels_index);
    printf("print(points)\n");
    printf("print(rectangels)\n");

    fclose(stdout); //needed?
    fclose(fp);
    return 1;
}
void printPointList(char appended, char** points, int index){
    if(!appended){
        appended = 1;
        printf("points =  [\n");
    } else {
        printf("points.extend(\n");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= index; i++){
            printf("%s,\n", points[i]);
    }
    if(!appended){
        printf("]\n");
    } else {
         printf("])\n");
    }
}
void printRectangleList(char appended, char** rectangles, int index){
    if(!appended){
        appended = 1;
        printf("rectangle =  [\n");
    } else {
        printf("rectangle.extend(\n");
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= index; i++){
        printf("%s,\n", rectangles[i]);
    }
    if(!appended){
        printf("]\n");
    } else {
        printf("])\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken but I think this could be 2 separate questions that would target two very different set of reviewing skills. You have C code that translates text into python code, which will then print shapes?

Comment: You assume correctly. I only care for the C code.

Comment: Or at least not so much about the python code.

Comment: Is there any reason for `points.extend` at all?

Comment: Sure, writing everything in one list makes it unreadable. So I thought chunking would sustain some readability...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Choice of language

I understand you probably want to do this in C, but I felt it was worth mentioning that Python is a much more suitable language for this task.

### malloc call

You're using `points = malloc(SPACE_FOR_POINTS * sizeof(char*))`. I'll advice you to instead use `points = malloc(SPACE_FOR_POINTS * sizeof(*points))` to prevent problems if you change type of `points` in the future.

### Comparing pointers to NULL

Not a big deal, but checking if a pointer is valid with `if(ptr)` or not valid with `if(!ptr)` is so common in C that it adds almost no readability.

### Comments

You're using some unmotivated comments. Like when you are wasting 7(!) lines just to explain why you are using `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

### return instead of exit

Using return instead of exit works as long as you're in the main function. So if you have a return statement that should quit the program, then instead use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` so that it does not matter if you refactor it into a function.

### Massive main function

The thing that strikes me most is that you have a massive main function with a really huge switch statement. The first thing I would do put the whole switch statement into a function with the signature `enum state DFA(enum state state, char ch)` and then have a main loop like this:

```
for (char ch = fgetc(fp); ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(fp)) {
    state = DFA(state, ch);
    if(state == error) { /* Handle error*/ }
}
```

But this would not be enough, since your states are much more complicated than that. The actual state of your machine is a combination of `state` and `shape`. So I would rename the current `state`. I will choose `category` but I'm sure you can come up with something better. Then I would do this:

```
struct state {
    enum category;
    enum shape;
};

struct state DFA(struct state state, char ch);
```

Of course, you would also need to pass `rectangles`, `points`, `rectangles_index`, `points_index` and `actual_index` somehow. I would use a struct for that:

```
struct data {
    char **rectangles;
    char **points;
    size_t rectangle_index;
    size_t points_index;
    size_t actual_index;
};

struct state DFA(struct state state, char ch, struct data * data);
```

Another alternative would be to just declare them as globals. Don't think that would be a too terrible idea in your project.

### Massive switch

I would consider rewriting the whole automata. I would have rewritten it a bit like this:

```
switch(state) {
case name:
    nameFunction(ch, data); break;
case openparen:
    openparenFunction(ch, data); break;
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your suggestion; I also considered reducing the size of main but was not sure about the concrete design-choice. My goal is indeed writing this in C, so I learn C. 
In Python, I would have considered this way to easy, since there are fundamentals I do not have to care about. I think I will create more complex compiler-exercises in python in the future and hope for your review :)

Comment: Why would you not pass pointers into the DFA and return void? What does state mean?

Comment: Okay, while refactoring I figured out why. Because you have to dereference tons of time!